# How do I open a file that is part of my solution?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a document that I have included in my VS 2010 solution.  It is in a folder called "MyFolder" the file itself is called "MyDoc.docx".  I've tried the following ways to open the file but none work:

```
Stream s = File.OpenRead("/MyFolder/MyDoc.docx");
```

and

```
Stream s = File.OpenRead("MyFolder/MyDoc.docx");
```

and

```
Stream s = File.OpenRead("~/MyFolder/MyDoc.docx");
```

What is the proper path for this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using (var s = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("~/MyFolder/MyDoc.docx")))
{
    ...
}
```

where `~` indicates the site root. Also make sure you grant the account your site is running under read permissions to this folder.

Comment: If a .docx file is plain text, someone's abusing file extensions.  ".docx" is the extension for Word 2007 documents, which are basically zip files with XML and other stuff inside.

Comment: It's actually being used by a third party software called Aspose.

Comment: @cHao, oh my, you are totally right!!! I didn't even look at the extension. Removing this aberration from my post :-) Thanks for noticing.